# How do I remove Ubuntu, wipe hard drive and Mac

Tags: xubuntu, mac, macosx

I bought a Samsung SSD 128 GB for my MacBook Pro 13 Mid-2009, 2.53GHz 8GB RAM.

I want to try Ubuntu on it so I installed it first. Everything went fine, but after a couple of weeks I wanted to switch back to OS X. So I booted with the OS X disk and erased the SSD, but I can't install OS X. Disk Utility won't let me erase the disk anymore or create a partition. It says error wrong output input.

I have also removed the SSD and used it externally trying to completely wipe it, but it doesn't work.

Results of `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` :

```
Device contains neither a valid DOS partition table, nor Sun, SGI or OSF disklabel 
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xdaa79ffb. 
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them. After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.

Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by write
```

Answer (score 2):

Use any "boot CD" with utilities (a lot of such kind of CD you can find in the network (for ex., Heren Boot CD, etc)
Than load your computer and start `fdisk` (MSDOS fdisk sw) After, type in command line:

`fdisk /mbr`, then you can try to edit / delete the patrition(s)

After that, you should be able to load any new OS there..Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a new partition table.

1. Boot from a LiveCD
2. Find out what drive your ssd is (for example sdX)
3. Install a GUID-partition editor (`sudo apt-get install gdisk`) *Note: this installs the application temporary, you will need to do this every time you boot from a live cd*
4. Open this drive with gdisk `sudo gdisk /dev/sdX`
5. Write'n'exit (`x`); appearantly this converts the MBR to a GUID
6. Optionally: try opening the disk again (with gdisk) and create a partition
7. Reboot with your Mac installation medium

The gdisk usage comes from the [Arch GUID wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#GPT_fdisk). I have not tested this information, in doubt, please consult the [gdisk manpage](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/gdisk.html).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. 
So i did the following:
- booted from ubuntu cd 
- used "try before installing", 
- opened terminal and wrote the commands sudo fdisk /dev/sda (my ssd was sda) 
- used o and x as commands. 
- exit ubuntu 
- then i put my osx disc in and booted, 
- used disc utility to fromat the drive to hfs+ but it said "POSIX reports: The operation couldnt be completed. input/output error." 

i cant install osx if the hard drive isnt formated to hfs+

Comment: Ok, so Macs don't like MBR paritions, they use GPT tables; i've updated the answer to reflect a more mac-compatible process

Answer (score 0):

Use **Gparted** to erase the partition and leave the disk **unallocated**